# In Haproxy how do I forward to a custom 404 page but still return a 404 status code?

Tags: haproxy

I have a haproxy default backend configured to be S3 and it hold static files.
My problem is ... in the event that a route falls thru to the default backend and then fails to find the resource I want to capture that 404 and display my own custom 404 page (which is also on the same S3 backend location) but still return a 404 status.
I have this so far but it relies on a redirect 302 which is the status returned to the browser and I want a 404 (/404.html is my custom 'not found' page);

```
backend static_s3
  errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/index.html  
  http-response set-header Location /404.html if { status eq 404 }
  http-response set-status 302 if { status eq 404 }
...
```

So I want to see my custom 'not found' page but the browser recognises it as a 404 status code, can it be done?

p.s. it would be good if Haproxy allowed you to do something like this in the backend section;

```
errorfile 404 /etc/haproxy/errors/404/index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, it is difficult to modify the body of an http response with HAProxy, so you may want to try one of these alternatives:

1. If you can use CloudFront instead of your S3 bucket directly, you can [configure CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/custom-error-pages-procedure.html) to return a custom 404 error page.
2. If you can switch your reverse proxy to nginx, you can set an error page pretty easily with the `error_page` directive

If neither of these alternatives work for you, you can use Lua to internally do the redirect.  Here is a stack overflow answer that outlines how to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50872246/33254).

Comment: ty ... yes I can use CloudFront, so if I create a new 'default backend' (for all my unknown/uncaptured routes) and send those routes to a new CloudFront 404 page, how will that return a 404 status rather than a 200?

nginx - not an option
Lua - yes read a bit about this but looked like a few moving parts that I wasn't ready for yet ... could be plan #c or #d tho :)

Comment: Sorry should have read up on the CloudFront (CF) link ... so I create a new CF location, have my default backend point to that new location, setup my new CF location with a rule to show my custom 404 page in the event of a resource not found on my new CF location and also return a 404 status?

Comment: @Billy if you plan to use CloudFront, you can setup Error pages on CloudFront. For 404, set the status code as 404 and choose the page which you want to load in error page document. Remember to choose status code 404 in error page.

Comment: I have spiked this out and it works, many thanks to you both :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following, which will show your 404 while returning a 404 status code rather than a 302 redirect.

1) Set your default backend to be the 404 backend.

```
default_backend static_404
```

2) Define your 404 backend.

```
backend static_404
  errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/index.html  
  reqirep ^Host:\ (.*) Host:\ yourbucketwiththe404.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
  reqirep ^(.*\ /)(.*)$ \1404.html
  http-response set-status 404
  server static-404 yourbucketwiththe404.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:80 check
```

You might want to add conditions to the `reqireps` to prevent executing them when loading your 404's assets (i.e. scripts and stylesheets), otherwise, they will throw 404s as well.